# Добавить/удалить fragment при нажатии на кнопку android

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-button

У меня есть приложение с двумя кнопками и textview. Одна из кнопок добавляет на mainActivity в контейнер fragment а вторая его убирает, и так можно бесконечно делать, то есть например мы нажав на кнопку добавили fragment а потом мы его можем удалить из контейнера. Так вот мне не очень понятно как сделать что-бы эта программа работала вышеупомянутым образом. Я думаю что нужно создать несколько фрагментов, и дальше при нажатии на кнопку добавления кидать этот фрагмент в контейнер, что-бы в итоге насколько я понял эти фрагменты были расположены как-бы стопкой. Я уже много где искал ответ на интересующий меня вопрос, а именно как повесить на кнопки добавление и удаление фрагментов из контейнера. В данной программе textview используется как счетчик фрагментов, то есть первый фрагмент вывели и в textview появилась цифра 1, итд. Ну это я думаю можно будет сделать так - нажатия кнопки будут увеличивать значение в textview на 1 до определенного числа. Если кто знает как работать с фрагментами то буду рад вашим советам.

Comment: у вас вопрос про то как добавлять и удалять фрагменты динамически?) через `FragmentTransaction` `ft.add(containerId,fragment)`

Comment: да вопрос, в целом и про это тоже, но для динамического добавления нужно ли предварительно добавить fragment через New->Fregment->Fragment(Blank) или же программа сама будет добавлять и удалять фрагменты при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку?

Comment: Давайте отделим мух от котлет: `New->Fregment->Fragment(Blank)` - этим Вы создаёте новый класс фрагмента. Если Вы будете использовать какой-то готовый, то естественно этого делать не нужно. При нажатии на кнопку Вы будете создавать инстанс этого класса и добавлять/удалять в контейнер. Заранее создавать кучу фрагментов что бы потом когда-нибудь их показать не следует. Никаких стопок делать не нужно - меняем один фрагмент на другой методом `replace`. Или используем готовые решения для навигации типа `ViewPager`